# Определить, что MediaPlayer завершил проигрывать трек

Tags: delphi

Как понять, что MediaPlayer завершил проигрывать трек?

Мне нужно, чтобы когда трек заканчивался, форма закрывалась сама.

Answer (score 2):

Используй св-во Mode, и событие ONNotify.
Напомню какое бывает свойство Mode:

```
TMPModes = (mpNotReady, mpStopped, mpPlaying, mpRecording, mpSeeking,mpPaused, mpOpen);
```

Думаю по названию всё понятно.

Итого, всё что нужно:

```
procedure TForm1.MediaPlayer1Notify(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if MediaPlayer1.Mode=mpStopped then Form1.Close;
end;
```